# Google Map multiple route with live update for new coming routes

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I want to show live multiple routes over google map, my condition is here I want to push new coming routes over map without flickering the map. I'm using below example right now to show multiple routes.

jsfiddle.net/mattlokk/mp3q292r/15/

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean without flickering.

Does it flicker when you add routes with the "Add Route" button?

If yes you can show a loader on top of the map for a second or two and then hide it.

```js
var routes = [];
var colors = ["blue", "red", "green", "black", "cyan", "brown", "purple"];
var map, directionsService;

function initialize() {
  routes.push({
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(34.04429454929703, -118.22793351693724),
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(33.688522885631706, -116.15151750131224),
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    waypoints: []
  });

  routes.push({
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(32.69561555501597, -117.06338273568724),
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(34.525395303965354, -117.27212297006224),
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    waypoints: []
  });

  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.5584308, -70.8597732),
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
    directionsService.route(routes[i], displayRoute(colors[i]));
  }

};

function displayRoute(color) {
  return function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        polylineOptions: {
          strokeColor: color
        },
        suppressMarkers: false,
        suppressInfoWindows: true
      });
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('add-route').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(34.04429454929703 + Math.random(), -118.22793351693724 - Math.random());
  var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(33.688522885631706 + Math.random(), -116.15151750131224 - Math.random());
  var route = {
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    waypoints: []
  };

  routes.push(route);

  var color = colors[routes.length - 1];
  directionsService.route(route, displayRoute(color));

  if (routes.length === colors.length) {
    this.style.display = 'none';
  }
});


document.getElementById('add-waypoint').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * routes.length);
  var route = routes[rand];
  route.waypoints.push({
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(34.04429454929703 + Math.random(), -118.22793351693724 - Math.random()),
    stopover: true
  });

  var color = colors[rand];
  directionsService.route(route, displayRoute(color));
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  display: none !important;
}

#add-route {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 1px;
}

#add-waypoint {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script async defer type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7lDrYPDmJz1JsQh2rbWA9uRZHcFk_xJY&callback=initialize"></script>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>

<button id="add-waypoint" title="Randomly adding waypoint">Add Waypoint</button>
<button id="add-route" title="Add random route">Add Route</button>
```

Comment: thank you your help that's near what I need, do you know how we can clear the previous routes before adding new and how can add point C in every route.
I'm using this code to clearing the old routes but its clear only one route.
  directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
  directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: []});

Comment: @GouravKumar in order to remove a specific route I think you can remove it from the `routes` array and then call again `directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: routes});` and to add third point you simply need to update the specific route in the array before calling the `setDirections` method

Comment: @GouravKumar example is extended now. It is showing a dynamic adding of waypoints

Comment: @downvoter tell some arguments for the down voting, before/after doing it